# Pre-select option in select with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

How can I pre-select an option, when I have the options repeated using ng-repeat, as so:

```
<select data-ng-model="info.country" ng-change="changeCountry()" name="country" required>
<!-- <option selected disabled hidden value=''></option> -->
     <option data-ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.countryName}}</option>
</select>
```

The `data-ng-model` returns the number `3` , the method `ng-change="changeCountry()"` uses the same number in its implementation.

I need the pre-selected item to be `3` and not `1` (this will be reduced by 1, since it is an array, but I think you get the idea)

I need to pre-select the item. Is this possible, and how can one achieve such result?

**[CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/sqnkov/pen/XWmOXYP)**

Comment: can u please share the `countries` example

Comment: @MaximShoustin - https://codepen.io/sqnkov/pen/XWmOXYP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` on `<options>` converts `id` to string. This is a reason why it doesn't work.

`{"country":3}` vs `{"country":"3"}`

You can solve it by using `ng-options`:

```
 <select data-ng-model="info.country" 
            ng-change="changeCountry()" name="country"             
            ng-options="c.id as c.countryName for c in countries"            
            required>

    </select>
```

Comment: Yes, this explains the problem in its root. Thanks for the clarification! Kudos for that.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this by using `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="country.id as country.countryName for country in countries" ng-model="info.country" ng-change="changeCountry()" name="country" required></select>
```